# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, jdbc

Вот такая ошибка появляется при попытке подключения. Но появляется, если запускать jar-файл не из папки проекта. В папке проекта работает как надо.
Используется NetBeans, и если правильно понял, то переменную classpath трогать не надо. Просто добавить в проекте драйвер. В общем, как запускать jar не только из папки проекта?

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` используется.

Comment: Файл с драйвером лежит рядом с тем файлом который запускаете?

Comment: Нет, файл лежит в папке \NetBeans\modules\ext\mysql-connector.jar

Comment: А вот в папке проекта dist\lib лежит mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
И в манифесте jar файла конкретно указан путь 
     Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
И как быть в такой ситуации? Таскать этот файл всегда с собой?

Comment: Получается что если создать отдельно папку lib и скопировать куда mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar то jar работает независимо от папки. Но это же не правильно. Как сделать что-бы mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar не требовался в виде отдельной папки с файлом.

Comment: Если mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar  добавлен во внутрь исполняемого jar файла, и указан Class-Path, то все должно работать, и всего один файл.  В NetBeans при формировании jar файла нужно указывать все лишь "создание файла с зависимостями".

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где этот дивный чекбокс? Есть "Отслеживать зависимости Ява" и "Копировать зависимые библиотеки".  А вот "создание файла с зависимостями" не нашёл.

Comment: "Копировать зависимые библиотеки" это оно и есть, я привел в кавычках, т.к. работаю в другой ИДЕ

Comment: К сожалению не проходит. Если даже убрать папку lib, а mysql-connector перенести в другое место, то в манифесте остается ссылка на папку lib.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте открыть zip архиватором исполняемый jar файл, в нем поидее должна быть такая структура:

```
jarname.jar
| /META-INF
| |  MANIFEST.MF
| |    Main-Class: com.mydomain.mypackage.Main
| |    Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
| /com/mydomain/mypackage
| |  Main.class
| mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
```

т.е. в Class-Path должен быть указан относительный путь на файл и все должно работать с одного исполняемого файла. Также посмотрите вот данный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7598688/6752984)

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.4
Created-By: 1.8.0_66-b18 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: condb.ConDB

Comment: Т.е идет ссылка на папку lib. Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov,спасибо за развернутый ответ, но всё же. Как встроить сторонний jar, в свой?

Comment: Ссылка идет на папку lib, а в самой этой папке есть mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar, в исполняемом jar?

Comment: В исполняемом jar данной папки нету. Как её туда встроить - неизвестно. В этом как раз и проблема получается.

Comment: добавил ссылку в ответ, попробуй решение по этой ссылке

Comment: А ссылка где? Я вот нашёл ещё решения, но так и не понял что и как делать.
http://javatalks.ru/topics/8535    
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/single-jar-141905.html

Comment: [вот ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7598688/6752984) , попробуйте правой кнопкой на папке lib нажать и выбрать "добавить библиотеки"

Comment: Это чуть не то. Так добавляются сторонние jar. Я так и добавлял.

Comment: В общем решение нашёл тут: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/single-jar-141905.html
Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Добавьте правильный ответ (дополните вопрос), чтоб он был на видном месте и у других была возможность сразу решить вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans собирает проекты с помощью Apache Ant. Netbeans по умолчанию создаёт папку lib, куда копирует все необходимые для работы вашего проекта библиотеки. Это как бы для вашего удобства, чтобы вам при дальнейшем запуске вашего проекта из командной строки не надо было писать длинный CLASSPATH. Все необходимые настройки на этот счёт есть в файле build.xml в папке вашего проекта. Вы можете внести необходимые коррективы в этот файл по своему усмотрению. Так же вы можете воспользоваться для сборки проекта другим инструментом, например Maven или вообще компилятором из состава JDK. И да, если для вашего проекта требуется какая-либо библиотека, вам придётся "таскать" её с собой. "Встраивать" библиотеку внутрь вашего jar я бы не рекомендовал, к тому же это не всегда допустимо лицензионным соглашением к библиотеке.

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы нашёл тут: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/single-jar-141905.html

В кратце:
Изменяется файл build.xml, перед закрывающим тегом "/project>" в конце файла добавляется следующий код:

```
  <target name="package-for-store" depends="jar">

    <!-- Change the value of this property to be the name of your JAR,
         minus the .jar extension. It should not have spaces.
         <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
    -->
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>


    <!-- don't edit below this line -->

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

</target>
```

В строке

```
<property name="store.jar.name" value="MyJarName"/>
```

Значение value заменяется на название своего проекта.

После на вкладке "Файлы" выбираем свой проект->build.xml->правой кнопкой->Выполнить цель->Другие цели->package-for-store.
В результате в папке проекта создается папка "store" содержащая упакованный результатирующий файл.

Всем спасибо за участие и помощь.